# Page loading and Selenium - Driver not doing anything after it loads

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I'm trying to automate (Java + Selenium) the testing of site but I'm having a lot of problems with the waits and getting it to do what I want.

Once I have a couple of unit tests ready my problem is this:
* If I don't put any waits and just execute the code firefox boots up, page loads and doens't do anything else. I was under the impression that the page would load before returning control but that doesn't seem to happen here. If instead of running it I put a breakpoint, debug it and run it step-by-step everything works perfectly so that's making me believe it is a timing issue.

If I write this then it works well too:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But if I want it to wait for an element to be visible (like the username or password field) or for a button to be clickable (like the login button) the cursor stays in the URL bar and it does absolutely nothing beyond loading the page.

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_E']"))));
```

(Yes, I know I could be using the ID instead of the xpath, it's a leftover from one of my many attempts).

After that piece of code it should do a few sendKeys() on two text fields then a click() on the login button and stop. Do I need to add anything else to actually execute the wait command or should that be enough?.

I know I'm probably messing it up somewhere in a rather stupid way but I just can't for the life of me find it or figure it out on my own.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how are you clicking the submit button.

Comment: Sure, something like this -> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_E']")).click().

Comment: @Arran: Not sure how to post the complete code here so here is a link to it -> [link](http://pastebin.com/UFc2sasg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are clicking your submit button. But It should go the way below

```
// WebDriver instance for explicit wait by default on until condition
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
// waits until elements gets ready 
WebElement we = wait
              .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                            .xpath("//*[@id=\"searchSubmit\"]")));

//  once elements is ready it will clicked
driver.findElement((By) we).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"searchSubmit\"]")).click();
```

[Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm having the driver find elements by either ID or xpath with the submit button being found by xpath so after the wait I posted before I do "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_E']"))". Could you explain this line a bit better please? "driver.findElement((By) we).click();", didn't know the bolded part could be written like that. I'm taking it looks for the webElement you found on the previous step, right?.

Comment: @Laucien I updated the answer. Try this way. I also added link which can help you. I just played with selenium in my free time so I am not pro in this.